# NSView Autosize (Vertically)

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview

Is it possible to have an NSView autosize (vertically) to fit its contents? The contents are just two NSTextFields, one (on top of the view) that's always the same height and the other (near the bottom of the view) that's of a variable height.

Something that could make it more difficult is that the NSView is an NSCollectionViewItem's view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the width needs to be known before the height can be calculated.  A successful implementation requires two layout loops.  The first determines the width.  That width is then taken and the height is calculated.  A constraint is then added or modified to reflect the height and layout must happen again.

To achieve this, I subclassed the view to store a copy of the frame size locally.  When the contents of the view changed, I would clear the width to zero.  If the actual frame rectangle width was discovered to be different than the stored width after layout, then I knew that height needed calculated and another layout needed to be executed in the event that the width change caused a height change.